# Escape MYSQL injection with GET method

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I generate a mysql query via `$_GET` in PHP via concatenation assignment (`.=`).
take a look:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM table WHERE ';
$sql.='ID='.$_GET['id'].'';
$query=$PDO->prepare($sql);
```

how can i prevent mysql injection?
i use bind values for direct queries but in this case,i don't have any idea how i should write my code to be safe enough.
note that i use PHP 7 and i can't use `mysql_real_escape_string();` as it's not available in PHP7.

Comment: Loop over the `$_GET` and put a placeholder in for each value, then bind the values. Current example should be `$sql='SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = ?';` then do prepare as you have and `$query->execute(array($_GET['id']));`

Comment: `$sql.='ID=?';` then `$query->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following:

```
<?php
$sql = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=?");
if ($sql->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
  while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>
```